Do the latest iOS (18) and watchOS (11) do not track “Time in Bed?”
Do the latest versions of watchOS and iOS log “Time in Bed?” If so is there a new setting that needs to be enabled in order for that to happen?
Until recently both Apple Watch 4 and my iPhone 13 Pro (running iOS 17) recorded “Time in Bed” as expected.
Then I updated from iOS 17 to iOS 18, without making any changes to my sleep settings or sleep schedule, and since doing that only Apple Watch 4 recorded “Time in Bed.”
I then upgraded to an Apple Watch 10 (running watchOS 11), and it too stopped recording “Time in Bed.”
Sleep stages are unaffected and continue to recorded correctly.
Is this the intended behavior? So the new iOS and watchOS no longer record “Time in Bed?”

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
